# Quadratic equation approach used in one of the gre questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, quadratics

Below is one of the gre practice question which i was able to solve but could not understand why my first approach dint worked.

[image: Gre Question]

In order to find the value of x, I used the below quadratic equation but it dint worked out well.

$x^2+2x+1=24$

Since $x^2,(x+1),x$ accounts to 24% ($100-76$) of the pie chart.

$x^2+2x-23=0$

Even though the above expression is correct (in context of the question) it does not work well to find the value of x, since above does not have a proper whole-number solutions of x.

On 2nd try i tried below equation and it worked well.

$x^2+2x-76=100$

$x^2+2x-24=0$

$x=-6$ or $x=4$

Now my intent of asking this question on forum is to get a better insight on why my 1st approach dint worked, even though both the equations mentioned above were correct in context of the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on my mistake, i am unable to find it.

Comment: In the second equation, you didn’t write the $1$... $(x^2+2x+1)+76 = 100$. That leads back to the first equation when simplified. So, your answer $4$ gives a total of $101$, which isn’t correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your first equation is correct, not your second. You forgot to add the $+1$.

$$(x^2+2x+1)+76 = 100 \implies x^2+2x+77 = 100 \implies x^2+2x = 23$$

This is the first equation again, and since $23$ is prime, this can’t be solved with integers.

$$x^2+2x-23 = 0 \implies x = \frac{-2\pm\sqrt{2^2-4(1)(-23)}}{2(1)} \implies -1\pm 2\sqrt 6$$

Since $-1-2\sqrt 6$ is negative, the answer becomes $-1+2\sqrt 6$%. Slightly awkward, but correct nonetheless...